# How to Get and Set Digital Signatures with FDA 21 CFR Part 11 Standards

Tags: compliance, digital-signature

How do I get and set digital signatures with the 21 CFR part 11 standards as defined by the Food&Drug Administration of the USA?

Answer (score 6):

Reading the [regulations](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfcfr/cfrsearch.cfm?cfrpart=11) themselves is a big start there. I'd also look at the [most recent guidance](http://www.21cfrpart11.com/files/fda_docs/part11_final_guidanceSep2003.pdf) that I've found. As I quickly interpret it, these aren't digital signatures in the way that most of us are familiar with. Rather, they are fields on data set by a controlled process which requires authentication, creates audit logs, and is under appropriate controls.

I'd implement something like that with a table that links signatures to document ids and records all entries with sequential numbering.

Beyond that, you're probably into needing to pay for consulting work.

Comment: Thats what i get after reading the rules, im so lost...
 
is there a free signature service? all that i found are so expensive. thanks –

Comment: You're seeking guidance on something that is a very broad concept and dependent upon a lot of details about your needs. If you're completely lost, you need to have somebody else more seasoned in this are to look at this for you. This is a systems design and internal controls problem.